# How do I add a column in an attribute table using QGIS graphical modeler?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, model

I have started to make a model in QGIS 2.2 graphical modeler. I have made a buffer around a polyline and used it to clip a polygon layer. So far i t works.

But the next step is to add a new column to the clipped polygon layer, and get that column to include rownumber? I have done this outside of the model before, but I don't understand how to make it work inside the model? I tried using the algorithm 'Field calculator' but it doesn't work.

How do I use the field calculator inside a model?

EDIT: Is there any other way of adding a column with rownumbers to the attribute table inside the model? I got the tip to use the 'Advanced Python field calculator' in an answer below, but I don't understand how to use it.

[image: screenshot python field calculator]

Comment: Hi,the field calculator that's available in the modeler works only with Python. The regular field calculator is not yet available. See: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9402

Comment: OK, I'm pretty new at this, does that mean that I need to know programing to be able to use the calculator? Is there any other way besides the calculator to get the job done?

Comment: @FilipeDias, I forgot to notify you in my previous comment. Do you know if there is anothor way besides the calculator? Without knowing programing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Advanced Python Field Calculator works. The Syntax is a bit diffrent but `value = $id` should work.

Comment: I've tried that, but I don't seeem to get it right. I chose a name for the new field ('index') and put value = $rownum under 'Formula', and an output name. But when I tried to run the model, I get 'Error executing algorithm 2 __init__()takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)'.

Comment: Sry for the wrong statement. The documentation for the python calculator is only available in russian... `value = $id` works in my case.

Comment: thank you for your update, that worked fine! If you update your answer with value = $id, I will set it as my accepted answer.